# image population using process.env.PUBLIC_URL

Tags: reactjs, populate

i am doing a project to populate image. i have already stored the path in database. and here i am using process.env.PUBLIC_URL to populate the data but i am not getting that image populated. the code which i wrote is given below.

code:-

```
export default class Sliders extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      evArray:[],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('/getallevlst')
    .then(res=>{
      this.state.evArray = res.data
      this.forceUpdate()
    })
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.evArray)
    const settings = {
      className: "center",
      centerMode: true,
      infinite: true,
      centerPadding: "24%",
      slidesToShow: 1,
      speed: 5000,
      width:"851px",
      infinite: true,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 7000,
      nextArrow:false
    };
    return (
      <div className="r-slider-main-section">
        <Slider {...settings}>
        {this.state.evArray.map(item=>
          <div className="r-slider-spacer">
          <a href="#" onClick={this.props.events}>
            <Card style={{borderRadius:"17px"}}>
            <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + item.logo} onerror={this.src=process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/assets/img/tos_logo.png'} className="r-test1" />
            {/* <img src={image2} className="r-test1" /> */}
            <img src={image1} className="r-test2"></img>
            <img src={calender} className="r-calender-place"></img>
            <text className="r-text-month">DEC</text>
            <text className="r-text-date">1</text>
            <text className="r-text-event-name">@{item.name}</text>
            <text className="r-text-event-detail">{item.event_type} featuring {item.name}</text>
            <div className="r-rectangle-icon"><div class="r-rectangle"><div className="r-rectangle-text">{item.amount}</div></div></div>
          </Card></a>
        </div>)}
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

the path which i give is `/react/public/assets/image/image.jpg`

thanks in advance

Comment: There are not enough details to help you. What's the content of your `env` file ? Have you tried without `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` ? If yes, does it work ? What's the content onf your `evArray` ?

Comment: its a path... sorry for late update. right now i have updated it above

Comment: If you replace `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` directly with your path, does it work?

Comment: ya.. its working... thank you

Comment: Hi are you using `create-react-app`?

Comment: Then, it means that something is wrong with `process.env.PUBLIC_URL`. Have you tried using [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)?

Comment: no... i didnt used that one

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack) package to load `.env` file and access to them from all over the React application.

**Usage**

Installation:

```
npm i -D dotenv-webpack
```

Create a .env file:

```
PUBLIC_URL=127.0.0.1
```

Add it to your Webpack config file:

```
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv()
  ]
  ...
};
```

Use in your code:

```
console.log(process.env.PUBLIC_URL);
```

Resulting bundle:

```
console.log('127.0.0.1');
```